# Empty file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a file named DBFile.
I am using the following code:

```
QString DBfile ="C:/Users/E543925/Desktop/VikuTB.xml";
QFile newFile(DBfile);
newFile.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly);
```

Now I want to write something inside the file if it is empty.
How can I check whether a file is empty or not in Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the append flag and check the insertion `pointer`:

```
newFile.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Append );
if (newFile.pos() == 0) {
  // is empty
} else {
  // some data inside
}
```

disclaimer: untested code, now i'll take the time to try it...

*edit*: tested, seems to work well...

Comment: I have no idea why this is the accepted answer. @VladGordin has the right one. This here doesn't work (at least in Qt 5.4). QIODevice (which a file is) supports the size() function which accurately returns the size of the device.

Answer (score 9):

Check file size before open by **newFile.size()**